# S3 Bucket .txt.gz Copy Via PySpark

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am using Python 2 (Jupyter notebook running PySpark on EMR). I am trying to load some data as a dataframe in order to map/reduce it and output it to my own S3 bucket.

I typically use this command:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('file:///home/path/datafolder/data2014/*.csv')
```

This is failing to work for when the file is in S3 and not my own bucket (as I am not sure how to format the `.load` command) which is most of my use cases now. My files are also a mix of .csv and .txt.gz, both of which I want in csv format (unzipped) when copied over.

I had a look on google and tried the following commands in Python 2 (Jupyter notebook):

```
import os
import findspark
findspark.init('/usr/lib/spark/')

from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

import sys

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
else:
    from urllib import urlretrieve

# Get file from URL like this:
urlretrieve("https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/path/path2/path3/path4/path3/results.txt.gz")
```

Which simply outputs: `('/tmp/tmpmDB1EC.gz', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x7f54db894758>)` so I'm unsure what to do now.

I have read through the documentation, and searched this website and Google for simple methods on forming the df but am stuck. I also read up about using my AWS key / secret key (which I have) but I could not find an example to follow.

Can someone kindly help me out?

Answer (score 0):

you need to load it using the spark context

```
data_file = urlretrieve("https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/path/path2/path3/path4/path3/results.txt.gz")

raw_data = sc.textFile(data_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried this but I got this error: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o29.textFile. Also, I'm unsure if this is scalable i.e. I can read in multiple paths like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240271/reading-multiple-s3-folders-paths-into-pyspark?

Comment: sc.textFile("s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/path/path2/path3/path4/path3/results.txt.gz") perhaps?

Comment: I then get this error: NameError: name 'urlretrieve' is not defined. urllib is not available on Python 2. The issue is I need to be able to copy multiple S3 paths (ideally convert to an unzipped CSV) and merge together in a single dataframe in order to do a map/reduce and output to my S3 bucket. I can't seem to find a solution for this.

Comment: why would you get that from running sc.textFile("s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/path/path2/path3/pa‌​th4/path3/results.tx‌​t.gz") it doesnt use urlretrieve?

Comment: also you can just load multiple like this and then use union operation

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting the error: NameError: name 'urlretrieve' is not defined. I am using the 3 lines of code above (from pyspark ... SQLContext(sc)) and then using the 2 lines you mentioned (including https:, removing it, adding the time zone of the S3 bucket etc) all with the same error.

Comment: just using the string alone? ignore the urlretrieve line, don't use urlretrieve

Comment: Do you mean: rdd = sc.textFile("s3://blah.csv"). That works but when I do any calculation e.g. rdd.count() or rss.show(5) or try to convert the RDD to a dataframe e.g. df.createOrReplaceTempView("test") it fails saying AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'show'.

Comment: I realised the problem. When I installed EMR, I opened a Python 2 notebook, not a Spark notebook. This was causing the issue. It was basically trying to run commands through Python rather than PySpark.