# Running queries directly on partitioned files using Pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark

[Here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#run-sql-on-files-directly) it is mentioned that we can run a query directly on a single file like this.

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM parquet.`examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet`")
```

My question is can we do this on a set of files partitioned as yyyy/mm/dd ? 
In the same page it says spark can automatically discover partitions. I am not sure how to do it for this type of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your having a **parquet table** with nested `partition fields` as
`yyyy/mm/dd` then give the **table location directory** in your query then spark can read all the **nested partitions and create an dataframe**.

**Example:**

I have a table with 3 partition string fields (year,month,date)

```
hive> desc i;

+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
|         col_name         |       data_type       |        comment        |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
| id                       | int                   |                       |
| year                     | string                |                       |
| month                    | string                |                       |
| dd                       | string                |                       |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # Partition Information  | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| # col_name               | data_type             | comment               |
|                          | NULL                  | NULL                  |
| year                     | string                |                       |
| month                    | string                |                       |
| dd                       | string                |                       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--+
```

Now i'm trying to load the data by reading parquet files( table location is `/apps/hive/warehouse/i`).

**Files in HDFS:**

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /apps/hive/warehouse/i
drwxrwxrwt   - hive hadoop          0 2018-11-03 00:10 /apps/hive/warehouse/i/year=2018
drwxrwxrwt   - hive hadoop          0 2018-11-03 00:10 /apps/hive/warehouse/i/year=2018/month=10
drwxrwxrwt   - hive hadoop          0 2018-11-03 00:10 /apps/hive/warehouse/i/year=2018/month=10/dd=15
-rwxrwxrwt   3 hive hadoop        214 2018-11-03 00:10 /apps/hive/warehouse/i/year=2018/month=10/dd=15/000000_0
```

**Now read the data from pyspark:**

```
>>> df=spark.sql("select * from parquet.`/apps/hive/warehouse/i`")
>>> df.columns
['id', 'year', 'month', 'dd']
>>> df.show(10,False)
+---+----+-----+---+
|id |year|month|dd |
+---+----+-----+---+
|1  |2018|10   |15 |
+---+----+-----+---+
```

In case if you want to read only the specific year files then

```
>>> df=spark.sql("select * from parquet.`/apps/hive/warehouse/i/year=2018`")
>>> df.columns
['id', 'month', 'dd']
>>> df.show(10,False)
+---+-----+---+
|id |month|dd |
+---+-----+---+
|1  |10   |15 |
+---+-----+---+
```

There is no column for **year** because we are **not reading year data** using pyspark and we are `reading only the month,dd and id fields` data from parquet files.

> **UPDATE:**

In case of csv files we can follow `similar approach as above` and we don't need to have `year,month,day` fields as **spark will create** those fields while reading the data in the directory.

***Read CSV files:***

```
#we are reading the csv files with header  
>>> spark.sql("""CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY view df
             USING csv 
             OPTIONS (header "true", path "/apps/hive/warehouse/i")""")

>>> df=spark.sql("select * from df")
>>> df.show(10,False)
+---+-----+---+
|id |month|dd |
+---+-----+---+
|1  |10   |15 |
+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: Thank you ! However, I am new to this whole pyspark environment. First, I am working with CSV files. Would it work for CSV files as well ? And do we have to have the year, month and day as columns in the csv files to do this ? When I said partitions, it meant csv files are just separated into folders based on year month and date there were created. Finally, do I need to run this command `hadoop fs -ls -R /apps/hive/warehouse/i` before running the query ?

Comment: @user2939212, Yes we can use similar approach for csv files also, Please check updated answer above. You don't have to run `hadoop fs -ls -R /apps/hive/warehouse/i` for **just demo purposes** i have ran that command to show directory structure :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this with information in here worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240271/reading-multiple-s3-folders-paths-into-pyspark. 
Do you know how to find the documentation about these commands ? I was not able find any documentation on these statements.

Comment: @user2939212, The documentation is all over the place(`official docs will have some basic ways to load the data` and **for advanced usage** i refer to stack overflow for documentation :)), check out this official docs from databricks, https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-csv.html#csv-files